# Ordering position "dodge" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Seems simple but i couldnt find a solution.

```
names(AllCoursesReg)
[1] "name"   "Course" "Status"
```

My Code

```
ggplot(AllCoursesReg, aes(Course, fill = Status)) + 
geom_bar(aes(order = Status), position = "dodge", colour = "black") + theme_bw()+
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

I just want the Registrants to be on the left not on the right.
I have tried Order, level, factor, and it is not working

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decide on the ordering of the levels of a `factor`. Here's an example from `?geom_bar`.

```
# example from ?geom_bar
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
# reorder cut using levels = rev(levels(cut))
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=factor(cut, levels = rev(levels(cut))))) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_discrete('cut') # change name back to cut
```

Comment: I am getting this, after applying it.Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length = n) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Comment: If the reproducible example that I made does not fit your case, you should make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) yourself. Otherwise we cannot diagnose the problem.

Comment: my example is complete and easy to understand.

Answer (score 26):

ggplot has been updated since this question, so here's an answer that utilises a new feature from ggplot2.

Just add *position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)* to the position attribute. Using OP's code:

```
ggplot(AllCoursesReg, aes(Course, fill = Status)) + 
geom_bar(aes(order = Status), position=position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), colour = "black") + theme_bw()+
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way of handling this now, none of the other options worked for me.

Comment: Great solution. I didn't need the `guides()` call in my code for the order to still match.