# Order of categories in ggplot with fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I've run this code:

```
#setup
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
library(scales)

#import data
tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load('2021-05-25')
records <- tuesdata$records

records_tt <- records %>% 
  mutate(track = factor(track), 
         type = factor(type))

#let's create a boxplot
records_tt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=record_duration, y=track, fill=type)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
  labs(x = "Record duration", y = "") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      margin = margin(t = 15)),
    legend.title = element_blank())
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image: Mario Kart plot]

I have three questions though:

1. What is `ggplot` using to decide which level of `type` to place on the top (i.e. why is it currently plotting `three lap` on the top and `single lap` on the bottom)?
2. How do I flip the order of the display, without changing the order of the legend keys (as it makes sense that single is listed on top of three)?
3. How do I reorder the values of `track` from lowest mean value of `record_duration` (independent of `type`) to highest mean value, instead of the default reverse alphabetical which is currently displayed?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438883/reorder-stacks-in-horizontal-stacked-barplot-r/36439557#36439557

Comment: That does show something which could become a solution to (3), but seems pretty complicated. I've found a simpler way -- am posting a solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For question 2: Here is a solution, borrowing from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700492/7010056): Switch out the call to `geom_boxplot` with the following line:

```
geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6, position=position_dodge2(reverse = T)) +
```

- For question 3: here's a solution:

```
records_tt %>% 
  group_by(track) %>% 
  mutate(mean_duration = mean(record_duration)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = record_duration, y = reorder(track, -mean_duration), fill = type)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6, position=position_dodge2(reverse = T)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
  labs(x = "Record duration", y = "") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      margin = margin(t = 15)),
    legend.title = element_blank())
```